# WPF Dynamically Populate UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How can I populate UI items such as a `textblock` for example, based on the contents of a `datagrid`?

For example, if i had a `datagrid` with a varying number of columns each with a specific header. Would it be possible to create a new `textblock` for each column with the content of text being the column header?

I'm trying to populate a list of column names and checkboxes based on the contents of my`datagrid` which has data pulled in from an excel file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to bind to `DataGrid`'s `Columns` property

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="DataGrid1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" Width="75" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" Width="75" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" Width="75" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 4" Width="75" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid1, Path=Columns}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataGridColumn}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Linq;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can modify `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>` to adjust an items appearance to your needs.

Comment: However if your datagrid and target control (which is to be bound to `DataGrid`s `Columns`) are on different controls, you might be not able to access to DataGrid via `ElementName` markup extension. If so, you'l have to pass binding via shared viewmodel / resource.